# patterns in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

if you have something like :

```
text
result
measure
text
measure
result
text 
result
text
measure
text
measure
result
text
measure
text
```

how could you extract each measure and result between 2 texts ,ok i extracted the results and measures that I want and stored them in variables but what can i do where i have :

```
text
measure
text
```

and I would like to extract the result as NULL in this case....

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  Given that fact, your question is totally unclear -- it seems to depend on the ordering of the values.

Comment: First of all, the table snippet you showed us is a bit meaningless because there is no column to specify an order, and the answer you get will almost certainly be order dependent.  Second, you might have an easier time doing this in another tool.

Comment: I am extracting the values from a text file and inserting them in my tables ,and yes I know it would be easier in another tool but sadly I do not have this choice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're pulling data in from a text file, then your best option is probably to set up the table you're importing to with an identity field so that as you load it, the values are assigned a number in order:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE
        (RowNum INT IDENTITY
        ,val VARCHAR(36));

INSERT  INTO @table
VALUES  ('text'),
        ('result'),
        ('measure'),
        ('text'),
        ('measure'),
        ('result'),
        ('text'),
        ('result'),
        ('text'),
        ('measure'),
        ('text'),
        ('measure'),
        ('result'),
        ('text'),
        ('measure'),
        ('text');
```

The resulting table will then look like this:

```
RowNum  val
1   text
2   result
3   measure
4   text
5   measure
6   result
7   text
8   result
9   text
10  measure
11  text
12  measure
13  result
14  text
15  measure
16  text
```

From there we can go about finding the results and measures between the text.

```
SELECT  Results.Result
       ,Measures.Measure
FROM    ((
          SELECT RowNum AS Start FROM @table WHERE val = 'text'
         ) AS A
         OUTER APPLY (
                      SELECT TOP 1 RowNum AS [End] 
                      FROM      @table endTab 
                      WHERE     val = 'text' 
                                AND A.Start < endTab.RowNum
                      ORDER BY RowNum
                     ) AS B
         OUTER APPLY (
                      SELECT TOP 1
                                val AS Result
                      FROM      @table resultTab
                      WHERE     val = 'result'
                                AND resultTab.RowNum BETWEEN A.Start AND B.[End]
                     ) AS Results
         OUTER APPLY (
                      SELECT TOP 1
                                val AS Measure
                      FROM      @table measureTab
                      WHERE     val = 'measure'
                                AND measureTab.RowNum BETWEEN A.Start AND B.[End]
                     ) AS Measures);
```

First, we need to get the positions of each text record and its following text record. Then we can look for the first Result record and Measure record within the start and end.

```
Result  Measure
result  measure
result  measure
result  NULL
NULL    measure
result  measure
NULL    measure
```